# SQL Server Select Count in Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the count of News ,  it gives me error

Column 'News.NewsId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
select    News.NewsId
        , News.NewsTitle
        , COUNT(News.NewsId) as Total 
from News inner join NewsCategory on News.NewsId = NewsCategory.NewsId
where NewsCategory.CategoryId in (Select CategoryId 
                                  from Category 
                                  where CategoryName = 'travel' 
                                    or  CategoryName = 'Technology' 
                                    or  CategoryName = 'Sport')
```

Comment: Are you wanting to aggregate the results by `newsid`?  Meaning do you want multiple records returned?  If so, you are simply missing the `group by` clause.  Add this to the end: `group by news.newsid, news.newstitle`... If not, you should better define your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ti like this:

```
select    News.NewsId, News.NewsTitle, COUNT(News.NewsId) as Total from News  group by  News.NewsId, News.NewsTitle
inner join 
NewsCategory
on News.NewsId = NewsCategory.NewsId where NewsCategory.CategoryId in (Select CategoryId from Category where CategoryName = 'travel' or  CategoryName = 'Technology' or CategoryName = 'Sport')'Technology' or CategoryName = 'Sport')
```

You are using count that's why you need to group by the field,include at your count(News.NewsId)

This one displays count for every category according to each NewsId:

```
select count(1), a.NewsId, a.NewsTitle,b.category from
(select  NewsId, NewsTitle from tbl_news)as a


left JOIN

(select    NewsId, categoryid,Category  from tbl_category) as b
on a.newsid = b.newsid GROUP BY a.NewsTitle,b.category
```

Comment: It's working, thank you :) But the count is always 1, I need to get the Count or the number of news under each category. like category Sport has 2 news and category Technology has 4 news, Can you please help me to solve this, Thank you

Comment: you mean count per each category?

Comment: Yes ... Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: helloo are you there?

Comment: i don't even know your db design.. just making some solution for you. Hope you can add more details here for your result

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the column `NewsId` and `NewsTitle`

```
select    News.NewsId
        , News.NewsTitle
        , COUNT(News.NewsId) as Total 
from News inner join NewsCategory on News.NewsId = NewsCategory.NewsId
where NewsCategory.CategoryId in 
                        (Select CategoryId 
                         from Category 
                         where CategoryName IN ('travel','Technology','Sport'))
GROUP BY News.NewsId
        , News.NewsTitle
```

Or you can write the query as

```
select    News.NewsId
        , News.NewsTitle
        , COUNT(News.NewsId) as Total 
from News 
inner join NewsCategory on News.NewsId = NewsCategory.NewsId
inner join Category     on Category.CategoryId = NewsCategory.CategoryId
where Category.CategoryName IN ('travel','Technology','Sport'))
GROUP BY News.NewsId, News.NewsTitle
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write this using two joins and a `group by`:

```
select n.NewsId, n.NewsTitle, COUNT(*) as Total 
from News n inner join
     NewsCategory nc
     on n.NewsId = nc.NewsId join
     Category c
     on nc.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
where c.CategoryName in ('travel', 'Technology', 'Sport')
group by n.NewsId, n.NewsTitle;
```

Comment: It's working, thank you :) But the count is always 1, I need to get the Count or the number of news under each categories. like category Sport has 2 news and category Technology has 4 news, Can you please help me to solve this, Thank you